# Refund for Flight Cancellation - SATA

Tags: air-travel, eu, cancellations, compensation

Many months ago, SATA (now known as Azores Airlines) canceled a flight from the Azores to Boston on which my wife and I had confirmed passage. EU regulations are clear that under the circumstances which obtained, we were owed financial compensation. I wrote to the carrier providing all details and citing regulations, but have received only automated replies to my original message and numerous follow-ups. Anyone have relevant experience? What's the best way to contact the EU regulators?

Answer (score 2):

Writing letters to the airlines might not help as airlines always try to ignore your emails and letters as they do not want to pay compensation to the passengers.

In most of the cases, airlines would lure you by giving you coupons and discounts on flight bookings just so that you don't claim compensation. It may be the case where you might not be writing a correct legal letter, you can find such flight delay compensation letter templates online.

Another thing you can do is contacting an online claims company. Such companies will claim compensation for your delay and you will get your compensation with very minimal charges. The best part about such online claims companies is that you do not have to pay any money if they do not win your case.

I hope my answer will help you in claiming compensation for your cancelled flight.

Comment: I have found online claims companies that represent only EU residents. (I live in the U.S.) There has been advice about the proper form that appeals directly to the airline should take, but I have been stonewalled by SATA for over a year now> Does anyone know how to appeal to EU regulators directly?

Comment: I have experience with these guys https://www.claimflights.co.uk, they assist both EU & International citizens to claim compensation from airlines.